# list index out of range error with functions

Tags: python, list, function, range

```
import math
lst=[]
abc=[]
lstt = []
def phi(i):
    sum=0
    global lst
    global abc


    for b in range(1,i):
        for a in range(1, b):
            if math.gcd(b,a)==1:
                sum=sum+1
        if(sorted(list(map(int,str(b))))==sorted(list(map(int,str(sum))))):
            lst.append(b)
            abc.append(sum)
        else:
            sum=0
    return abc, lst
def asd():
    v = 0
    global lstt

    for v in lst:
        lstt.append(float(lst[v-1]/abc[v-1]))
    return lstt
```

calling phi function works fine but after calling asd function,I get list index out of range error. 
When I test different function with different lists,it works just fine

```
def hh():
    abc=[1,2,3]
    lstq=[5,6,7]
    v = 0
    lsta = []
    for v in abc:
        lsta.append(float(abc[v-1]/lstq[v-1]))
    return lsta
```

code above works fine

Comment: `v` is the value in the list and not index inside `asd` function

Comment: Can you post the piece of the code that gives you the error when you run it?

Comment: It looks like you're using `for v in abc` when you meant to use `for v in range(len(abc))`